# Linux append text to ifstat output

Tags: linux, bash, append

I'm trying to append text to each line that is coming out from ifstat Linux utility.
Example:

```
ifstat -t -w -i eth0
```

output:

```
HH:MM:SS   KB/s in  KB/s out
01:37:55   0.09     0.30
01:37:56   0.09     0.13
```

I want to append to each line the output of another command:

```
ethtool eth0 | grep "Speed"
```

so that the resulting output will be as shown below:

```
01:37:55      0.09      0.30   Speed: 100Mb/s
01:37:56      0.04      0.13   Speed: 100Mb/s
```

I tried using **sed** command but without significant results.

Comment: Invalid time interval

Comment: What does that mean? Could you explain?

Answer (score 0):

Process Substitution and `paste` plus `sed`

```sh
paste -d ' ' <(ifstat ... | tail -n+2 ) <(ethtool ... | sed '/Speed/p')
```

Comment: Thanks to all. It works as expected: now I need to add information to the log. I have a background c++ application that receives temperature data from the network and I need to add that info to the previous log. The problem is that the process that collects data and the one that prints log on the terminal aren't synchronous. So I thought that the process that collects data from the network could update an environmental variable that could be read from bash, or maybe using shared memory. Any other simpler ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this seems to work:

```
#!/bin/bash
# File name: combine.sh

timeout "10s" ifstat -t -w -i eth0 |
    while read line; do
    SPEED=$(sudo ethtool eth0 | sed -n '/Speed/p' )
    echo "$line" "$SPEED"
    done
```

The output needs work but it roughly does what you want.

```
$ /bin/bash /tmp/combine.sh 
Time        enp0s31f6   Speed: 1000Mb/s
HH:MM:SS   KB/s in  KB/s out    Speed: 1000Mb/s
02:44:45      3.07      4.99    Speed: 1000Mb/s
02:44:46      2.19      1.06    Speed: 1000Mb/s
02:44:47      1.12      0.88    Speed: 1000Mb/s
```

Adjust the `"10s"` to `"60s"` if you want it to last a minute instead of 10 seconds.

Note: This answer inspired by an `inotifywait` script I wrote based on [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/323919/411854) Stack Exchange answer which pipes a continue stdout stream into a while loop, performing an action on each line as it comes in.

Comment: Thanks to all. It works as expected: now I need to add information to the log. I have a background c++ application that receives temperature data from the network and I need to add that info to the previous log. The problem is that the process that collects data and the one that prints log on the terminal aren't synchronous. So I thought that the process that collects data from the network could update an environmental variable that could be read from bash, or maybe using shared memory. Any other simpler ideas?

Comment: Using a bash environment variable sounds weird but would probably work. Personally I'd write separate log files for each stream split by day which a separate script then can sample to periodically generate an automatic report.

Comment: I had the same idea, but I need to update a real time graph.